# How can I find Nth element of an xml object

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cc

I'm trying to get sub elements of elements of an xml file. I tried using nested loops such as:

```
for each (var tempNode:XML in menu_xml.elements())
{
    if (tempNode.children().length() > 0)
```

however couldn't accomplish that. Even if this this code works it will get elements for limited stages.

How can I get sub elements one by one, or is there a simpler way to do this?

**EDIT:** Here's the sample xml content:

```
<mainmenu>

    <home/> 
    <portfolio/> 
    <contact/> 
    <friends>
        <bestfriends>
            <joe/> 
            <karen/> 
            <bob/> 
        </bestfriends>
        <otherfriends>
            <john/>
            <peter/>
        </otherfriends>
    </friends>

    <animals>

        <cat/>
        <dog/>
        <horse/>

    </animals>

</mainmenu>
```

**EDIT 2:** I havent decided how to use these nodes. Say I'll parse them to an array. arr[3][0][0] should be joe.

Comment: How about using a recursive function ?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I don't think it's something more special than loops. but I'd be glad if you give me an example.

Comment: @onurcano22 could you start providing an example please? It's so far entirely unclear to me what the XML file looks like, which of its elements you want to access and what you want to do with them. Please elaborate!

Comment: @onurcano22 Here's a basic example: ```var testXML:XML = <root><l1><l2><l3/></l2></l1></root>;

trace(getNames(testXML));

//recursive
function getNames(xml:XML):String{
 var result:String = xml.localName();
 var childrenLen:int = xml.children().length();
 if(childrenLen > 0){
  for(var i:int = 0 ; i < childrenLen; i++) result += "->"+getNames(xml.children()[i]);
 }
 return result;
}
``` You should be able to achieve the same with loops indeed...regarding recursion it's a matter simplicity, not efficiency

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I'm working with your code. I'll tell if it works.

Comment: Did you know you can access nodes in an XMLList using array brackets? So `xml.friends.bestfriends.children()[0]` would give you `<joe/>`.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use E4X? Here you can find some explanations:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html

Comment: sorry for the late response, I'll try that.